# Unit test fails (custom validate method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

Here is my model validation

```
validate :validate_mark_cheat

def validate_mark_cheat
  if (self.student_from_id == self.student_to_id)
    errors.add(:student_from_id, "a mark can't be self-asign")
    errors.add(:student_to_id, "a mark can't be self-asign")
  end
end
```

Here is my unit test

```
test "Mark can't be self-given" do
  mark = Mark.new(:student_from_id => 1, :student_to_id =>1)
  assert mark.invalid?
  assert mark.errors[:sudent_from_id].any?
  assert mark.errors[:student_to_id].any?
end
```

I can't figure out why my test fails

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You realize you misspelled :student_from_id in the test?

Comment: No biggie, everyone does it at some time. :)